# Install Angular CLI on Google Cloud Shell

Tags: google-app-engine, angular-cli, npm-install, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to install the `@angular/cli` npm package inside of the Google Cloud Shell. When I run `npm install -g @angular/cli` the package manager does through and starts trying to perform the install and then fails with a permissions issue.

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v6.9.2/lib/node_modules'

I've tried to run this with `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` but the terminal tells me:

> NPM: command not found"

I tried to perform the installation to my $HOME instead, using this gist, but accessing the `~/.bashrc` file is denied.

What am I supposed to do in order to install global node packages like this?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$ sudo -i npm install -g @angular/cli
```